# how to handle data validation without wrapping everything into try/catch

Tags: php

Does someone have a good practice to handle data validation before inserting into database without the need to wrap everything into try/catch?

```
try{
    (new DB_table)->put();
}
catch(User_error $e){
    echo "Error: Something could not be validated!";
}

class DB_table extends DB {
    public $name = 'john doe';
    public $address = 'tall cedar road 123';
    public $email = 'john@doe.com';

    public function put(){
        $this->validate_name('name');
        $this->validate_address('address');
        $this->validate_email('email');

        if($this->errors){
            throw new User_error();
        }

        // insert data into database
    }
}

class DB {
    protected $errors = [];

    protected function validate_name(string $key){
        try{
            $this->$key = trim($this->$key);

            // some validation
            throw new Input_error('Name could not be validated');
        }
        catch(Input_error $e){
            $this->errors[$key] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    protected function validate_address(string $key){
        try{
            $this->$key = trim($this->$key);

            // some validation
            throw new Input_error('Address could not be validated');
        }
        catch(Input_error $e){
            $this->errors[$key] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    protected function validate_email(string $key){
        try{
            $this->$key = trim($this->$key);

            // some validation
            throw new Input_error('E-mail could not be validated');
        }
        catch(Input_error $e){
            $this->errors[$key] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

class Input_error extends Error {}
class User_error extends Error {}
```

Comment: boolean usage could be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate your validation logic from your `DB_table` class.

You could create a validator class that returns true/false if the stuff was validated.

If you use a Framework, they probably have something like this already. Otherwise you could implement your own and get inspired from [Laravel's Validator](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html)

Its used like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        //if you reached this line, then feel free to insert into DB
```